# How to log Redux actions with additional state-change details per action

Tags: redux

I have a Redux application where I will be logging my user's actions, and would like to log my actions to different places (e.g. my log file; my error log if there is a problem; Google Analytics). Currently, each place has its own middleware

```
/middleware
  log_action_to_file.js
  log_some_actions_to_analytics.js
```

My action objects are terse, and contain just the information needed to make a state-change. However, for a human-readable log, it is useful to have more information, typically the result of the action. In theory we could just add a `diff` of the state, but in practice the readers of my log would like something more semantically meaningful:

```js
// actions
{
   type: "MOVED_FORWARD_X_PAGES,
   numberOfPages: 5,
   // nowShowingPage: 53         <== log file would like this additional info
}
{
   type: "SELECTED_ITEM_FROM_LIST,
   index: 4,
   // itemSelected: "cheese"     <== log file would like this additional info
}
```

I could have a separate file with a whole list of actions that specifies the additional properties that need to be logged:

```js
export function addPropertiesBeforeLogging(action, nextState) {
  let loggableAction = { ...action};
  if (action.type == "MOVED_FORWARD_X_PAGES") {
    loggableAction.nowShowingPage = nextState.showingPage;
  } else if (...)
```

But then every time I add a new action I need to remember to update this file, and it would get very messy.

What's a better way of dealing with this? Should I add some additional info to the action-object itself, that self-describes what state data to add?

```js
//actions.js

export function moveForwardXPages(numberOfPages) {
  return {
    type: "MOVED_FORWARD_X_PAGES",
    numberOfPages
    additionalLogDataFromNextState: {
      nowShowingPage: "next.showingPage"
    }
  };
}
```

And then my middleware can parse that string to know what to query in the new state? Or is this coupling the state and the action too tightly? What's a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are in the right direction.
As you say, you could add a new field to your actions where put the extra informations you need to log. For example, if you look the [FSA (Flux Standard Action)](https://github.com/acdlite/flux-standard-action), it allows a property `meta` for this purposes.

> The optional meta property MAY be any type of value. It is intended for any extra information that is not part of the payload.

To log your action a good solution is to use a one or more dedicated `redux-middleware` charged for this which catch every action with a special "trait".
For example you could mark the action with a symbol (ex. `LOG`) and easily catch it with the middleware or, alternatively, you could catch actions which present the property `meta`.

A little snippet inspired by [real-world](https://github.com/reactjs/redux/tree/master/examples/real-world) example in redux repo:

```
// LOG symbol
export const LOG = Symbol('LOG')

// action
import { LOG } from './....'
export function moveForward () {
return {
   [LOG]: {
       type: "MOVED_FORWARD_X_PAGES,
       numberOfPages: 5,
       nowShowingPage: 53        // <== log file would like this additional info
       }
}

// A Redux middleware that interprets actions with LOG info specified.
import { LOG } from './....'
export default store => next => action => {
  const log = action[LOG]
  if (typeof log === 'undefined') {
    return next(action)
  }
  // here perform log
  // ...
}
```

Take a look also a this library [redux-segment](https://github.com/rangle/redux-segment) (analytics integration for redux) which use the property meta to tell the middleware to log the action.

Hope it helps.

---

#### Update

I try to answer your questions below.

A good pattern with `redux` is to keep hidden the state shape to the action (and components). So pass the *path* of the item which you need to log in the action is not a great deal.

Said this, I don't know if there is a simple and elegant solution for your problems, but I try to give you some ideas :)

For example, instead of the *path* you could set in the action the name of the `selector` which you want to use to get the information to log.

With this arrangement:
- you decouple the action from the state, so in a future you can change the state shape without changing actions, but only changing the selectors
- you could use [reselect](https://github.com/reactjs/reselect) and compose more selectors to log more info
- you don't need to use `eval`
- you need to set a selector for every information which needs to be logged

Some code (not tested) to explain better what I mean.

```
// action moveForward.js
export function moveForward () {
  return {
   type: "MOVED_FORWARD_X_PAGES",
   payload: { numberOfPages: 5, nowShowingPage: 53 }
   meta: { selector: 'getShowedPage' }
   }
}

// action selectItem.js
export function selectItem () {
  return {
   type: "SELECTED_ITEM_FROM_LIST",
   payload: { index: 4 }
   meta: { selector: 'getSelectedItem' }
   }
}

// reducer pages.js
export default function reducer(state = initialState, action = {}) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "MOVED_FORWARD_X_PAGES":
      return Object.assign({}, state, {
          numberOfPages: action.payload.numberOfPages,
          nowShowingPage: action.payload.nowShowingPage,
          // ...
       })
  }

// reducer items.js
const initialState = { list: [], currentItem: undefined }
export default function reducer(state = initialState, action = {}) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "SELECTED_ITEM_FROM_LIST":
      return Object.assign({}, state, {
          currentItem: action.payload.index,
          // ...
       })
  }


// log_middleware.js
import logger from './logger'
export default store => next => action => {
    // if action not contains extra info to log (meta) go ahead
    if (!action.meta)
      return next(action)

    // Save current state and get the next one
    const prevState = store.getState()
    const returnedValue = next(nextAction)
    const nextState = store.getState()

   // Perform log 
   logger(prevState, nextState, action)

   // return the next state
   return returnedValue   
}


// selectors.js 
const getShowedPage = state => state.nowShowingPage
const getSelectedItem = state => state.list[state.currentItem]"

export default selectors = {
   getShowedPage,
   getSelectedItem
}

// logger.js
import selectors from '../selectors'

export default logger (prevState, nextState, action) {
    const selector = state => selectors[action.meta.selector]
    const infoToLog = selector(nextState)

    // Perform log
    console.log(infoToLog)
}
```

To compose more selector you could use [reselect](https://github.com/reactjs/reselect).

In conclusion take a look to [this](https://egghead.io/lessons/javascript-redux-colocating-selectors-with-reducers) video tutorial on selectors by D. Abramov and to [redux-logger](https://github.com/evgenyrodionov/redux-logger/blob/master/src/index.js) source code.

Comment: Thanks for this. What do you think of the question of an action wanting to define what should be logged *based on the next state*? E.g. `nowShowingPage` is based on the next state, and the action creator has no way of knowing the actual value until it's been dispatched. My method was to add a string representation of the state path to fetch from`next()`, but this seems a little like using `eval`, and I don't know if it seems clean. (It could also get complex: to get "cheese" from my second example, given just the index, I'd need to pass `itemSelected: "next.list[action.index]"` or something.)

Comment: @SamFen I have updated the answer with an idea on how you could face your problem using a `middleware` and the `selectors`. By the way, I don't know if it fit your requirements. Maybe using [redux-saga](https://github.com/yelouafi/redux-saga) can simplify the logging process.

Comment: Thank you. I haven't delved into `selectors` yet, but this seems like exactly the solution. Perfect.